# Xamarin Draw Lines On the gridlayout

Tags: android, xamarin

I have got an android app in Xamarin and a gridlayout form with numbers.
I want to draw lines of different width between this numbers.
How can i do this?

Thank you!

Comment: please post some code you already have and maybe a drawing of what you'd like to achieve

Answer (score 3):

If you want to draw the lines in different width, you have to write custom grid layout and draw your line in OnDraw override method,

```
public class GridLayoutExt : GridLayout
{
    public GridLayoutExt(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
        //This will enable the drawing of this Layout
        SetWillNotDraw(false);
    }


    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        //Draw your lins based on your requirement
        //canvas.DrawLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I Add this custom GridLayout to the form?

Comment: Do you mean Xamarin.Forms platform?